# how to solve php --ini “Loaded Configuration File:(none)”?

Tags: php

I am trying to install php from source code, but I got a problem here,
I googled it but nothing useful for me.
First, here is my install.sh

```
make clean

./configure \
        --prefix=/usr/local/programs/php5 \
        --disable-fileinfo \
        --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini \
        --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/ \
        --with-apxs2=/usr/local/programs/apache2.4/bin/apxs

if [  0 != $? ]; then
        echo "Auto installation failed! -- Configuration"
        exit
fi

make
if [  0 != $? ]; then
        echo "Auto installation failed! -- Make"
        exit
fi

sudo make install
if [  0 != $? ]; then
        echo "Auto installation failed! -- Configuration"
        exit
fi

echo "Copying the min size config file."
sudo cp php.ini.clean.bk /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini

if [ -a /usr/bin/php ]; then
        sudo rm /usr/bin/php
        sudo ln -s /usr/local/programs/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
fi

php --version
php --ini
```

After the script is done,  I got some weird information here:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini
```

Why `Loaded Configuration File:         (none)` is null, is there anything wrong during the installation ?

Also,

```
$ ls /usr/local/programs/php5/etc/
pear.conf  php.ini  php.ini.bk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/php.ini
```

is incorrect. You specify a *path* not a *file*.

```
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/programs/php5/etc/
```